# Getting an Arduino Uno and MKR zero to communicate

Tags: arduino-uno, audio, speaker

I'm very new to Arduino and especially the forum so please let me know if I am on the wrong topic or anything.

Anyways let me get straight to the point. I am working on a school project where I need to create a robot head that can move and talk using the Arduino Uno. I have the speech files as a .wav and from what I gathered you need an sd card reader connected to the Uno to read .wav files. So I purchased the Arduino MKR Zero, but after I got the board I realized that it is a standalone board, not a file reader for the Uno. This project is due next week so I need to figure out how to make the MKR Zero read the files and play them off the speakers but have it timed and programmed off the Uno. Is this possible with the hardware I have?

Here is a picture of my setup: 
[image]

Comment: you don't need the Uno

Comment: I do because the MKR Zero doesn't have enough ports for all the motors that I need to use for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the MKR Zero play the wav files. It has DAC on A0 and [AudioZero library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AudioZero) to play wav files from SD card.

You can use Serial communication to command the Zero from Uno. In Uno use hardware Serial or create SoftwareSerial to send commands to Serial1 of MKR Zero. You can then test the MKR first with commands sent from Serial Monitor.